# How to add padding to input field text [CSS]

Tags: css

I have a quick question, I know that I can edit a placeholder text for an input field using CSS. But I was wondering how I can add padding to the actual text (the text that the user types in). I have provided an image below, I have added padding to the placeholder text but am struggling to add padding to the actual text for the input field so that it is aligned with the placeholder text.

Here is what I have tried:

```
.form TextInput {
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

This obviously isn't working and I was just wondering if anyone else has a solution?

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5JabR.png)

**Edit:** I am not trying to move the input field itself, just the text inside. Just like I did with the placeholder, but only this time I want to move the text to match the position of the placeholder.

[Link 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/USR7J.png)

Comment: What is TextInput ?

Comment: @melvin It doesn't mean anything, I was just using it to explain what I am trying to do.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Padding on the input; for users typing in the field or a preset value parameter:

```
.form input[type="text"] {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Padding on the placeholder:

```
.form input::placeholder {
    padding: 10px;
}
```

Comment: I am looking to just move the text, not the input field itself.

Comment: Sure, just add a padding on the placeholder but not the input

Comment: I did that, I added padding on the placeholder. Now I want to add padding to the actual text that will appear when the user types some text in.

Comment: Yeah I provided both the placeholder padding and the input padding - targeting the input will appear when the user types some text

Comment: It's actually the opposite. I want padding on the actual text, I already have padding on the placeholder as shown in the first link I have provided. I want to move the text (not the placeholder) to the right without moving the input field itself.

Comment: Sure so you want the opposite the placeholder without the padding and the input with padding for users to type in?

Comment: Yes, I have added padding to the placeholder already. But when i add padding to the text the placeholder and the text are not aligned.

Comment: Ohh, I got it! Since I already padded the placeholder was why they weren't aligned. Ughh, I feel so stupid right now. I'm so sorry about the hassle. You know when you've been coding for hours and eventually your brain stops working, that's me right now. Time for a break haha. Thank you so much! I can finally catch some Zzzz's now! :)

Answer (score 3):

You have to give css to the input field as follows

```
.form input[type="text"]{
  padding:10px;
}
```

Check this fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/fjfyykvt/)

Comment: This would move the whole input field to the left 10 pixels. I would want to move the text that is inside the input field.

Comment: @howdydoo This won't move the input - you're confusing `padding` with `margin`

Comment: @Scoots Oh, my bad. But I don't understand how can I move the actual text inside the input field without moving the actual input field itself?

Comment: @howdydoo check the fiddle in my answer or https://jsfiddle.net/melvinstanly/fjfyykvt/

Comment: @melvin That's not quite what I mean. I just want to move the text, not the input field itself. In the link I have provided in my post you can see that the placeholder text is shifted to the right, that is exactly what I would like to do but only with the input text (not the actual input field itself).

Comment: @howdydoo I don't get how this moves your textfield

Comment: @mevlin Using padding extends my input field by 10 pixels using the code you have provided above. I am not trying to extend the input field itself, I just would like the text that the user types in to start further into the input field. I'm sorry if this doesn't make much sense. I am doing my best to explain this.

Comment: have you given width to input field ? @howdydoo

Comment: @melvin I'm not sure if you fully understand my question, I have provided a new link which will hopefully give a better idea :) Edit: I have given a width.

Comment: I got it! Turns out padding the placeholder and padding the input affected the result that I was expecting. Way too much coding for one day haha! Thank you so much! :)

Comment: @howdydoo. Hope it helped. Mark it an aswer if it was true

Answer (score 0):

1 - Padding for input, where user can type:

```
.form input.TextInput { 
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

2 - Padding for placeholder of input:

```
.form input.TextInput::-webkit-input-placeholder { /* Chrome/Opera/Safari */
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.form input.TextInput::-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 19+ */
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.form input.TextInput:-ms-input-placeholder { /* IE 10+ */
  padding-left: 10px;
}
.form input.TextInput:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
  padding-left: 10px;
}
```

Use css prefixes for cross-browser compatibility.